# C: setting an array member of a struct through a pointer

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct with an array as a member, and am trying to set that array using arrow syntax. What I have:

```
typedef float Foo[3];
typedef struct {
  Foo foo;
} Bar;

Bar* f() {
  Bar* bar = malloc(sizeof(Bar));
  bar->foo = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

  return bar;
}
```

gcc says:

```
error: expected expression before '{' token
```

on the line `bar->foo = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};`

I'm at a loss why this doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't `typedef` primitive types with abstract names like you are trying to do. It just causes headaches down the road.

Comment: @Tim Cooper: I agree, unfortunately it is beyond my control for this project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C99 allows it via compound literals:

```
Bar* f()
{
   Bar* bar = malloc(sizeof(Bar));

   if (bar)
       *bar = (Bar){{1.0, 1.0, 1.0}};

   return bar;
}
```

The “outer” curlies encapsulate the struct as a whole (if the struct had other members, you'd list them in the outer curlies), and the “inner” curlies are for the array.

Comment: Does this mean you can also do `bar->foo = (float[3]){1.0, 1.0, 1.0};`?

Comment: No, because `=` is not defined for array types, but it is defined for struct types (even for structs that contain arrays). See §6.5.16.1 for more information about assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Because C can't copy arrays through assignment. The only place that you can ever use the `{1.0, 1.0, 1.0}` syntax is in the initialization of a variable:

```
float foo[3] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
```

It's just not something that the language supports. It's possible that this is because that would allow the `=` operator to take an indefinite and possibly very long amount of time to perform the copy—it's a philosophical question.

Comment: `=` is well defined for structs. Even structs which contain arrays are assignable.

Comment: That's true, assignment works for structs. It's an obscure corner of the language that it works for structs that contain arrays. Something to take up with the designers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a supported syntax.  You can only initialize arrays when they are created -- you can't assign to one that is created.

Comment: Unless it is a member of a struct :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
float bar[3] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
float foo[3];
foo = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
```

That is an example of the difference between initialization and assignment, and there is no assignment operator for arrays in c.

Note however that you *can* do

```
Bar baz, quix
/* quix get setup some how... */
bar = quix;
```

because there is an assignment operation on `struct`s, which is how [dreamlax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011136/c-setting-an-array-member-of-a-struct-through-a-pointer/4011166#4011166) works.